# Button works on emulator but not on smartphone on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, styled-components

I have had a problem for several days, I have a list of items (a list of heads) and I want to be able to take action on these items (update/ delete).

I created an item component, with an update and delete button.

[image: item list]

The Button component is a component of react native elements, I use it everywhere in my app and I have not had any problems so far.

**ThemeItem.tsx**

```js
    <Container>
      <List onPress={() => onSelectTheme(theme.id)}>
        <ListItem.Content>
          <View
            style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 5}}>
            <ListItem.Title style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
              {theme.name}
            </ListItem.Title>
            {isActive && (
              <Icon
                name={'check-circle'}
                color={'green'}
                style={{marginLeft: 5}}
                size={20}
              />
            )}
          </View>
        </ListItem.Content>
      </List>
      <ThemeItemIconsStyle>
        <>
          {theme.id > 1 && !isActive && (
            <Button
              onPress={() => onDelete(theme.id)}
              icon={{
                name: 'trash',
                type: 'font-awesome-5',
                size: 25,
                color: 'white',
              }}
            />
          )}
          <Button
            onPress={() => onUpdate(theme)}
            icon={{
              name: 'pen',
              type: 'font-awesome-5',
              size: 25,
              color: 'white',
            }}
          />
        </>
      </ThemeItemIconsStyle>
    </Container>
```

**ThemeItemIconStyle**

```js
const ThemeItemIconsStyle = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

**Container**

```js
const Container = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
`;
```

On emulator the behavior is the one expected but when I install the apk on my phone it does not happen absolutely.

I absolutely do not understand why my code works on emulator and not on a real phone. I assume that if on emulator there is no problem, the problem does not come from the code.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

But what is the type of button? Button, TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityWithoutFeedback...

Also, I'd recommend to change your buttons to RectButton from react-native-gesture-handler, just to use native buttons in your application ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).